# What are examples of infinite-dimensional Banach spaces that are also measure spaces?

Tags: measure-theory, banach-spaces, hilbert-spaces, infinite-dimensional-manifolds

I am interested in examples of infinite-dimensional vector spaces that

- are Banach spaces or even Hilbert spaces
- are measure spaces

Instead of the full vector space, subsets with measure structure are interesting as well.

It is [well-known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite-dimensional_Lebesgue_measure) that any non-trivial measure in the infinite-dimensional case cannot be as nice as the finite-dimensional Lebesgue measure. But perhaps there is an interesting measure that is not translation-invariant or defined on a mere subset.

What are examples for such spaces, showing up in research in particular?

Comment: Look up Wiener measure.

Comment: For every random variable $X$ with values in a space $E$, the distribution of $X$ is a measure on $E$. In particular, for any random process we get a probability measure on the space of its paths --- a space of sequences for a discrete-time process, and a space of functions of real variable for a continuous-time process. Are those measures interesting? That depends on whether you consider those random variables and processes interesting.